# Python: Credit Card Validation Code

Tags: python, validation

I have a provblem with my code.
It is functioning pretty good but in some cases(such as input=8913266562747895) it gives wrong answers.
Here is my code:

```
def ccv(s):
    k=list(s)
    if len(k)==19:
        for i in(0,1,2,3,5,6,7,8,10,11,12,13,15,16,17,18):
            if not k[i].isdigit():
                return False
        for i in(4,9,14):            
            if k[i]!=" " and k[i]!="-":
                return False
        l=[int(c) for c in s if c.isdigit()]
        if not 4<=l[0]and l[0]<=7:
            return False
        s=0
        for i in range(0,16, 2):
            l[i]=2*l[i]
            if l[i]/10!=0:
                l[i]= l[i]/10+(l[i]%10)       
        for i in range(16):
            s=s+l[i]
        return s%10==0
    elif len(k)==16:
        for i in range(16):
            if not k[i].isdigit():
                return False
        l=[int(c) for c in s if c.isdigit()]
        if not 4<=l[0]and l[0]<=7:
            return False
        else:          
            s=0
            for i in range(0,16, 2):
                    l[i]=2*l[i]
                    if l[i]/10!=0:
                        l[i]= l[i]/10+(l[i]%10)       
            for i in range(16):
                    s=s+l[i]
        return s%10==0
    else:
        return False
n=raw_input()
while n!="END" and n!="end":
    print ccv(n)
    n=raw_input()
```

Can you tell me where is the problem?

Comment: This is the kind of code where it would help a lot to either break it up into smaller functions that each check for one state, or (even better) use a library that helps with CC validation.

Comment: Why not use a [regex for such matters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/creditcard.html)?

Comment: It's necessary to use python.

Comment: Please describe what "wrong answers" consist of. Give example input and output; explain your understanding of the problem.

Comment: Can u provide some sample inputs and outputs, so that it is clear what  this program actually does

Comment: The answer is True or False. I did give an example. I wrote that when the input is 8913266562747895 the output is True but it should be False

Comment: @damienfrancois: Because regex can't calculate the check digit (which I think this code is doing).

Comment: @GeorgeDavidKing: Why should it be false? `8913266562747895` is valid.

Comment: Don't argue about regex. I won't use it. Not because I don't want to but as they demand that the code is written in python

Comment: @Blender No, it's not. The first number(l[0]) should be: l[0]>=4 and l[0]<=7

Comment: Your test number 8913266562747895 [should in fact return `True`](http://creditcardity.com/?number=8913266562747895). Remember that even if you make up a completely random 16 digit number, it has a one in ten chance of being "valid", ie having the correct control sum.

Comment: @GeorgeDavidKing your 4 <= number[0] <= 7 rule is not true. See [Wikipedia - Bank Card Number - Major Industry Identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_card_number#Major_Industry_Identifier_.28MII.29)

Comment: @GeorgeDavidKing Python has a `re` module that lets you use regex *in* python.  So you can use both.  To my knowledge, there is no pure regex language anyway.

Answer (score 8):

I think what you're looking for is the [Luhn algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm). It can be implemented quite concisely like so:

```
def luhn(input):
    digits = [int(c) for c in input if c.isdigit()]
    checksum = digits.pop()
    digits.reverse()
    doubled = [2*d for d in digits[0::2]]
    total = sum(d-9 if d > 9 else d for d in doubled) + sum(digits[1::2])
    return (total * 9) % 10 == checksum
```

[Rosetta Code - Luhn Algorithm](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Luhn_test_of_credit_card_numbers#Python) has an even shorter version, that might be less readable though.

PayPal have published a good [list of fake credit card numbers](http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm) to test against.

Also check [pycard](https://github.com/orokusaki/pycard), a library with no external dependencies.

Comment: I tried it. It doesn't work

Comment: With your code it says:long' object is not iterable

Comment: @GeorgeDavidKing: "*Takes a credit card number in the form of a string*"

Comment: Ok.But now it shows another error: File "my_code.py2", line 11, in 
    print luhn(n)
  File "my_code.py2", line 5, in luhn
    digits = [int(c) for c in n]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'

Comment: I had a bug as well, i've posted the rosetta code version which I know to be right.

Comment: You probably have to clean your numbers from dashes and spaces etc. Only keep the digits.

Comment: Same thing: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_code.py2", line 8, in 
    print luhn(n)
  File "my_code.py2", line 4, in luhn
    r = [int(ch) for ch in str(n)][::-1]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'

Comment: Uhm, that says you still fed it a string that contains "-" and not only numbers.

Comment: Edited the rosetta code version to strip non-digits for you.

Comment: Now it's my code again, I thought the Rosetta Code version was hard to read.

Comment: It should be easy for you to add the 4 <= number[0] <= 7 check to this code, if it's a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is this line (and the duplicate line in the `else` block):

```
if not 4<=l[0]and l[0]<=7:
    return False
```

You need to use parentheses to make it parse in the right way:

```
if not (4<=l[0]and l[0]<=7):
    return False
```

Better yet:

```
if not 4 <= l[0] <= 7:
    return False
```

Comment: Still wrong. Try it yourself. input=8913266562747895 output=True

Comment: @GeorgeDavidKing: You didn't fix both `if` statements.

Comment: Hahahahahahaha!!! Nice! Thank you very much. You truly are a saver!

Comment: Another problem is that the function assumes all valid card numbers are 16 digits long, which is not the case. See [What your credit card numbers mean](http://www.computersolving.com/computer-tips-tricks/what-your-credit-card-numbers-mean/). In fact, they can have anything between 13 and 16 digits.

Comment: @AndréLaszlo: I don't think OP is checking actual credit card numbers.

Comment: @blender, Let's hope not :)